# unable to upload image locally

Tags: images, localhost, phpmyadmin

I followed [this tutorial](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion) on setting up a local web development setup without mamp. Now my problem is when I go to upload a image in WordPress I get the following error:

> “Screen Shot 2013-01-05 at 10.51.42 PM.png” has failed to upload due to an error:
>   Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/01. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

It seems like it might be some sort of permissions error, but I am not sure exactly what to change.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the [file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_FIle_Permissions) on your `wp-content` folder (and containing folders) to  `755`. On your setup you can do this with:

```
find . -type d -exec sudo chmod 755 {} \;
```

Please note that using `chmod -R 755` will mark both directories **and files** as 755.

Comment: Glat I could help! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct using the green tick to the left of my answer

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest way on a Mac is to right click on "uploads" , select "Get Info", then change the permissions at the bottom of the "Uploads Info" window to include read and write for the appropriate users.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the folder permission to 777 of wp-content.

Comment: *change folder permission of wp-content

Comment: Please edit your answer with more in-depth details on how they can accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: shea's answer sets the permissions to 755. Why is 777 better? And I realise the question is about a local development environment but leaving world-writeable files is a bad habit you don't really want to get into.